# How to loop on the list view (clientside to disable specific check box in)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a listview like this  :

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="rlv_available_sys" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="sys_holder"
                                DataKeyNames="process_id" OnItemDataBound="rlv_available_sys_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <colgroup>
                                            <col title="process name" />
                                        </colgroup>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_id" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("process_id")%>' />
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chb_sys" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_available_sys" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("process_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:RadListView>
```

---

and jquery :

```
addWidgetControls : function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings;

        $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
            var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
            if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
                $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();    
                }).click(function () {
                    if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                        $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                            opacity: 0    
                        },function () {
                            $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                                $(this).remove();
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
            }
```

---

What i want to do is :

When the user click close to remove the widget ,with some jquery way disable the intended check box and set checked = true.(How to modify the previous jquery to do this in client side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `settings.widgetSelector` selects the top element of a widget, that is, the table or a Telerik wrapper around it. I leave your other code intact:

```
 ...
 if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
     // reference to current widget wrapper
     var widget = $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector);
     // disable and select (all) contained checkboxes
     widget.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop({disabled: true, checked: true});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
     // animate and remove widget...
     widget.animate({
         opacity: 0
     ...
```

Note that this solution will disable and select *all* contained checkboxes in a widget. If you have multiple checkboxes and only need to select a single one, give it a class (e.g. `myCheckbox`) and change the selector to

```
     widget.find('input[type=checkbox].myCheckbox').attr({disabled: true, checked: true});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You should not use the existing checkbox ID if you have more than one widget, as element IDs should be unique for the whole document.

UPDATE:

Turned out that I misunderstood the problem: the checkboxes to be disabled are not inside the mentioned widgets and the actual task is to

> …disable the input type="checkbox" if the value of the input type ="hidden" that exist in the same  is equal to the id of the li (widget).

(See discussion in comments.)

This could be a solution:

```
...
$(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
    var widgetId = this.id; 
    var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(widgetId);
    if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
        $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();    
        }).click(function () {
            if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                // Disable checkboxes which have a sibling hidden input field with value equal to widgetId
                $(​'table tr input[type=hidden]').filter(function() {
                    return $(this).val()​​​​​ == widgetId;
                }).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').prop({disabled:true, checked: true});

                // animate and remove widget...
                $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                ...
```

Comment: Thanks but This doesn't work with me and even the widget can't be removed any more !!

Comment: Hm, I guess some copy & paste error happened here. If you comment out the `widget('input[type=checkbox]').attr({disabled: true, checked: true});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​` line you should have the same behaviour as before.

Comment: yes but how can i disable the intended `checkbox` in the list view ?

each widget is (`Li with id which = the hidden field value in the list view`)

Comment: Sorry, my bad: there was a typo in my answer (the `.find` call was missing in the first version. I've updated by answer...

Comment: hmmm ,it doesn't disable `checkboxes` .the check boxes are in the `radlistview`

Comment: Oh, now I get it: the widget's aren't your items in the code? Sorry, that was a bit misleading. Could you assign an individual ID to every checkbox, like `<asp:CheckBox ID="chb_sys_<%#Eval("process_id")%>" … />`? This way you can easily disable/select any checkbox by calling `$('#chb_sys_'+theProcessId).attr({disabled: true, checked: true});`.

Comment: hmmm the .net list view render this control to html :like this from the firebug:

Comment: `<table><colgroup><col title="process name"></colgroup>
<tbody><tr><td><input name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl0$hf_id" id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_hf_id" value="91" type="hidden">
<input id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_chb_sys" name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl0$chb_sys" type="checkbox">
<span id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_lbl_main_sys">pro1</span>                
</td></tr></tbody></table><table><colgroup><col title="processname">
</colgroup><tbody><tr><td><input name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl1$hf_id" id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl1_hf_id" value="92" type="hidden">`

Comment: `<input id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl1_chb_sys" name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl1$chb_sys" type="checkbox">
<span id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl1_lbl_main_sys">pro2</span> 
</td></tr></tbody></table>`

Comment: I wanna to disable input type="checkbox" if the value of the input type ="hidden" that exist in the same `<td>` equal to the id of `li`(widget).this when the user click close.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with a solution to this problem, have a look.

Comment: the widget is like this :

`<li id="91" class="widget color-red" name="0" runat="server" style="">
................
</li>`

Comment: `<li name="0" id="92" runat="server" class="widget color-white" style=""><div class="widget-head" style="cursor: move;"><a class="collapse" href="#">COLLAPSE</a><h3><span>header</span></h3><a class="remove" href="#">CLOSE</a><a class="edit" href="#">EDIT</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="edit-box"><li class="item"><label>Available colors:</label><ul class="colors"><li class="color-green"></li></ul></li></div><div class="widget-content"><span><p>content </p></span><ul><li style="list-style-type: none"><a target="_blank" href="https://aaa">q</a></li></ul></div></li>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you intend with your last comments. Does my update solve your problem? Please consider updating your question with the new information.

Comment: I tried your last update but in vain ,when i debug the code i find the id is empty, so I tried to explain the widget HTML to u .
my last comment is the HTML widget which is a listitem (`li`) has an id.

Comment: Ok, I gave it another try and edited my answer again (last part).

Comment: Wo0o0o0o0W , it works.thank u so much, i think the `jquery` is so powerful tool ,so i need to learn it. really thank us so much, i appreciate your great effort.

Comment: @ Julian D :one more thing, why when i have disabled checkboxes and i try to make the opposite set enabled = true . it doesn't work .

Comment: `$('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }).click(function() {
                    $td = $('table tr td input:hidden').filter(function() {
                        return this.value == widgetId;
                    }).parent('td');

                    if (confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                        $td.find(':checkbox').removeProp("checked").removeProp("disabled");`

This code works well in `firefox` , but in IE it doesn't Enable the check box !!

Comment: Try `$td.find(':checkbox').prop({checked: false, disabled: false});`.

Comment: just works with `firefox`, can't enable it in `IE`.Thanks a lot for your great effort.